# Running Prolog Sicstus through a shell file

Tags: shell, prolog, malloc, sicstus-prolog, halt

I've been trying to run a file through a shell script and write its output into that file.

The script is very simple:

/usr/local/sicstus4.1.1/bin/sicstus -l run --goal "runh('examples/calls_matlab.pl', S), halt." >  "/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/IP/modelling phase/rules.txt"

However, when I run this, it fails with the following error:
sicstus(24883,0x7fff70916ca0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10082b408: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

On the other hand, if I remove "halt" from the goal, everything's fine, but Sicstus is still running.

Is there a way to exit sicstus, without having to incur the error above through my shell script?

I appreciate your time.

Andreas

Comment: This smells of a bug in the SICStus-Matlab bridge. Complain to the person who wrote that.

Comment: the matlab generated file is perfectly valid. in fact if i run it in prolog (Without a shell script, everything is fine). what's causing error is the halt immediately after running the goal. I suspect that it tries to halt before finishing writing the output to the text file. I cant think of an alternative solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you run your script and redirect the input pipe with `/dev/null` ? And remove the halt option.

`/usr/local/sicstus4.1.1/bin/sicstus -l run --goal "runh('examples/calls_matlab.pl', S)." > "/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/IP/modelling phase/rules.txt" < /dev/null`

What I did was `sicstus -l my_file.pl --goal "test_strategy(10,random,random)." < /dev/null`

where `test_strategy` is my predicate which returns to shell.

Cheers,
Dan